# How to create refer and earn system in php oop

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I am creating custom e-commerce website in PHP OOP. Almost all (shopping system) things are done. I just wanna add referral system. But i am confused how to do.
When customer sign up then referral code/link should generate for that user and when customer share that link with his friends and his friends registered in our website then that customer who refers and who signed up using that referral code/link, both will get reward (price). Even, i didn't understand how to make structure. If you know about how to create this kind of system. Then at least guide me structure and how to create this.
**My users table is here:**
[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izwPF.png)

**My insert users function:**

```
public function createAccount($data){
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['last_name']);
    $phone_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['phone_number']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['password']);

    if($first_name == "" || $last_name == "" || $phone_number == "" || $password == ""){
        $msg = "Required fields can not be empty. Please fill the fields.";
        return $msg;
    } else if($this->checkPhoneNumber($phone_number) === true){
        $msg = "Phone Number is already in use. Try another phone number!";
        return $msg;
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, phone_number, password, authority, created_on) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name', '$phone_number', '$password', 'Customer' , NOW())";
        $result = $this->db->insert($query);
        if($result != false){
            $func = $this->loginDuringCreatingAccount($phone_number, $password);
            return $func;
        }
    }
}

public function checkPhoneNumber($phone_number){
    $query = "SELECT `phone_number` FROM users WHERE phone_number = '$phone_number'";
    $result = $this->db->select($query);
    $count = @$result->num_rows;
    if ($count > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function loginDuringCreatingAccount($phone_number, $password){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone_number = '$phone_number' AND password = '$password'";
    $resultS = $this->db->select($query);
    if($resultS != false){
        $value = $resultS->fetch_assoc();
        Session::set("userlogin", true);
        Session::set("user_id", $value['user_id']);
        Session::set("first_name", $value['first_name']);
        Session::set("last_name", $value['last_name']);
        Session::set("phone_number", $value['phone_number']);
        Session::set("password", $value['password']);
        header("Location: choose-username.php?step=last");
    }
}
```

Now, i have to update/add some column names in this users table or for that system i have to create new table. And if i have to create new table then i have to join users and that new table or not?

Can you please guide me to create this system?

Comment: Rough idea: Add a referal token to each user. When another user signs up they can enter a referal token from a different user into a new field in the register form, Or it automatically fills in when the token is found in a query parameter. Then when the registration is complete you can give them both their reward.

Comment: Can you please tell me about database table structure?

Comment: I am stuck, about database structure. Can you please tell me about database table structure for this system?

Comment: I think in its current from, this is rather too broad of a question for this site - and would suggest that you start by typing “how to create a referral system php mysql” or something similar into Google.

Comment: I have googled but these answers are totally different.

Comment: It surprises me that you made a whole shopping system but adding 1 field to the database is now difficult. Or maybe you make it way harder than it needs to be? Just give each user a referel token in the database. Like the user id, but a different field. Then after a user has registered with that referal token you can find who that token belongs to in the database and if a user is found then give them both their reward.

Comment: It's difficult for me just because i didn't done this before brother. Thanks for your help. I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to create refer and earn system in php oop**

Tables required

- Users (columns: User details with auto-generated refrel code)
- referral(columns:ReferedBy, ReferedTo, CouponId)
- Coupon(columns:CouponId, CouponType, CouponAmount)

Flow:

1. When new user signup, all the details with auto-generated referral code gets inserted in the Users table.
2. when another new user signup with referral code, all the details with auto-generated referral code gets inserted in the Users table, And we will fetch the userid on the basis of referral, then the data gets inserted in referral table.
   Coupon id will be based on Coupontype='Referral',
3. After than coupon will be send to both the users

Comment: I didn't understand what is the role of coupon table?

Comment: Today we have an only referral Coupon, it can be many more.

Comment: If you don't want the Coupon table, you can have the column 'Coupon sent' instead of 'CouponID' , which will be 'Y/N', when the coupon is sent